# Como alterar números na mesma linha de execução em Python?

Tags: python, terminal

Olá sou novo em programação e estava fazendo um programa de contagem regressiva em python.
Fiz o código e deu certo, mas então fiquei olhando o programa em execução e o mesmo  utilizando varias linhas só pra alterar o numero....Seria possível fazer com que só  altere o numero da contagem, sem aparecer varias linhas na execução?

Ai esta meu código, espero que entendam o que quis dizer...

```py
from time import sleep

for c in range (10,0,-1):
    print('Aguarde, seu programa vai começar em ',end='')
    if c > 1:
        print(f'{c}',end='')
        if c==10:
            print(' segundos',end='')
        else:
            print('  segundos',end='')
    if c == 1:
        print(f'{c}',end='')
        print('  segundo ',end='')

    for i in range (0,3):
        if c == 0:
            break
        print(' .',end='')
        sleep(0.33)
    print('')

print('Seu programa esta rodando!')
```

Answer (score 3):

O terminal onde o print exibe seu conteúdo é um programa especial que pode ter várias capacidades - elas são ativadas dependendo de códigos de controle que você manda dentro da própria string no print.

ENtão, por exemplo, para imprimir texto colorido, vários terminais, mas não o terminal padrão do Windows aceitam sequências do tipo `<ESC>[...m` - são chamadas sequências ANSI, (Para imprimir o código do ESC, numa string de Python usamos o seu código ASCII em hexadecimal, com a sequência `\x1b`.

Essas sequências ANSI incluem comandos para reposicionar o cursor em qualquer lugar da tela do terminal - você escolhe a linha e coluna onde quer imprimir. Aqui tem a documentação razoavelmente completa, bem como o histórico, dessas sequências: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

A Microsoft prometeu para esse ano um novo terminal no Windows 10, que deve substituir o `cmd` que deve ter essas sequências por padrão. Enquanto isso, você pode usar um programa chamado "[cmder](https://cmder.net/)" que é uma experiência de terminal de Unix no Windows - ou a biblioteca terceirizada "[colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)" para habilitar as sequências ANSI no `cmd`.

No entanto, há uma sequência mais simples, que funciona mesmo em terminais que estão com as sequências ANSI desabilidatas, que é o caractere backspacs - o Python tem a codificação especial `\b` para o mesmo que pode ser usada em strings.

Além dessa sequência, é importante personalizar a chamada ao print para (1), ela não enviar o "\n" ao acabar de imprimir e (2) não ficar aguardando o "\n" para atualizar o conteúdo da linha - essas duas coisas se faz passando-se os parâmetros `end="", flush=True` para o `print`.

Então, tente esse exemplo:

```
import time

print("Contagem regressiva")
for i in range(10, -1, -1):
    print(f"\b\b\b{i} ", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

No caso os 3 "\b" fazem o cursor recuar 3 posiçoes (se chegar na coluna 0 ele para), e o espaço " " depois do  "{i}", garante que ele apague o segundo dígito (o 0 do 10), quando a contagem passa a ser de um único dígito.