# ANSI no Visual Studio Code com Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Como faço para o vs code entender esta linha de comando:

```
print('\033[1mNome: ')
```

Onde "\033[1m" é a parte responsável por deixar em negrito, mas em vez disso ele está respondendo com isto:

```
?[1mNome:
```

Answer (score 3):

Nos terminais do windows, o suporte a sequências aNSI não vem ativado.

A forma mais fácil de fazer funcionar é importar a biblioteca terceirizada ["colorama"](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) (`pip install colorama`), e, no ínicio do seu programa, colocar as linhas:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

Ontem eu comentei um pouco mais sobre o mesmo assunto nessa outra resposta:
[Como alterar números na mesma linha de execução em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387893/como-alterar-n%C3%BAmeros-na-mesma-linha-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-python/387898#387898)